# Excel: date formula needed

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If date in column A is within 7 days of today then True., if not then false.

If have tried =IF, =CountIF, and conditional formatting.  I feel as though I am on the verge, but just missing it.

Comment: Additional Comment:  The formula I need will reside in column B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=IF(INT(A1-TODAY())<7, TRUE, FALSE)`

Comment: @chancea You should write the formula in B1 and drag it down to as many rows as you need.

Comment: @shruti1810 I get that...but this only checks one cell at a time was what I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

To check the whole column just use 2 criteria wihin the `COUNTIFS` formula:

Use `<=` and `>=` for inclusive 7 days:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<="&TODAY()+7,A:A,">="&TODAY()-7)>0
```

Use `<` and `>` for exclusive 7 days:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<"&TODAY()+7,A:A,">"&TODAY()-7)>0
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter version:

```
=A1-TODAY()<8
```